# Random sampling in pyspark with replacement

Tags: random, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe df with 9000 unique ids.

like

```
| id |
  1 
  2
```

I want to generate a random sample with replacement these 9000 ids 100000 times. 
How do I do it in pyspark

I tried

```
df.sample(True,0.5,100)
```

But I do not know how to get to 100000 number exact

Comment: To be clear, you need to take a random sample of 9000 ids, where each sample has 4,500 ids in it (which could repeat since we sample with replacement), and you need 100,000 of these samples?

Comment: 9000 is the population of distinct ids that I have, I want to oversample the population to 100000 with replacement and randomly. so in plain english, I want to pick up an random id 100000 times from a jar of 9000 ids in a random way. I hope this helps.

Comment: It did, thank you. I will try to work it through now.

Answer (score 16):

Okay, so first things first. You will probably not be able to get exactly 100,000 in your (over)sample. The reason why is that in order to sample efficiently, Spark uses something called [Bernouilli Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_sampling). Basically this means it goes through your RDD, and assigns each row a probability of being included. So if you want a 10% sample, each row individually has a 10% chance of being included but it doesn't take into account if it adds up perfectly to the number you want, but it tends to be pretty close for large datasets.

The code would look like this: `df.sample(True, 11.11111, 100)`. This will take a sample of the dataset equal to 11.11111 times the size of the original dataset. Since 11.11111*9,000 ~= 100,000, you will get approximately 100,000 rows.

If you want an exact sample, you have to use `df.takeSample(True, 100000)`. However, this is not a distributed dataset. This code will return an Array (a very large one). If it can be created in Main Memory then do that. However, because you require the exact right number of IDs, I don't know of a way to do that in a distributed fashion.

Comment: Hello Katya, Thank you so much for the answer. I did not get the exact count, but if its sampling in a way that I want it is good enough.

Comment: You probably mean df.rdd.takeSample() ? There is no such method df.takeSample()

Comment: .sample() does not work on dataframes for me though its given in documentation. It is working on RDD. What am i missing?

Comment: See the documentation http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample